# Problems with IntelliJ IDEA - incompatible types

Tags: android

When I try  `LocationProvider locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;` IntelliJ is giving me an error: `incompatible types: required: android.location.LocationProvider found: java.lang.String.`

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a project built in IDEA and haven't had this problem. Have you checked you are importing all the appropriate packages?

```
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.GpsStatus;
```

When you *rightclick/Go To/Declaration* LocationManager you should see the following code:

```
package android.location;

public class LocationManager  {
    public static final java.lang.String NETWORK_PROVIDER = "network";
    public static final java.lang.String GPS_PROVIDER = "gps";
```

**Update**

Ok. I know what is going on here. What you are doing is assigning a LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER (which is actually a string) to a [LocationProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationProvider.html) object. hence the incompatible types error.

Is there a reason you want to instantiate a LocationProvider object? Looking at the LocationManager API, you don't actually need one of these. The API takes the constant strings (GPS_PROVIDER, NETWORK_PROVIDER etc) and instantiates the appropriate LocationProvider internally. If you really need the LocationProvider instance, you can get it back from the LocationManager with the [getProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getProvider%28java.lang.String%29) method.

**Another Update**

So it looks like the reason the OP encounted this problem in the first place is that the sample code on the [Obtaining User Location documentation](http://d.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) is just wrong:

```
LocationProvider locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
// Or use LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER

Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
```

[LocationProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationProvider.html) is an abstract superclass and you shouldn't be instantiating these things directly. Instead you pass a LocationManager.type_of_provider_here into the LocationManager and it instantiates an object that implements that abstract class. So the sample should be:

```
Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

Comment: I've got `everything import android.location.*;`

Comment: @LuxuryMode Ok. So clearly not that. I am fiddling with my project to see if I can reproduce the problem and then work backwards. I'll let you know how I go.

Comment: @LuxuryMode What happens when you go to declaration on the LocationManager? (see my update).

Comment: I was just following along with http://d.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html The example shows: `LocationProvider locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;`

Comment: @LuxuryMode That just seems wrong to me. Do this instead (Having another look at the LocationProvider doco to see if there is a constructor that takes the LocationManager.<TYPE>): locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

Comment: @LuxuaryMode Yep. That documentation is just wrong. LocationProvider is an abstract superclass. You can't instantiate one of these.

Comment: Wow really appreciate you looking into this so thoroughly. More important than getting this to work was seeing how you thought through it. This is invaluable. Thanks!

Comment: @LuxuryMode No problems :) Happy to help.